# Referenced script on this behavior (gameobject 'player') is missing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am creating a scene in Unity3d and exporting its asset budle as .unity3d file. Further i downloading the assetbudle from my server to my android app. The scene gets loaded but rotaion script i have written for cube is missing. I can see the object in my android app from where i start UnityPlayerActivity but object is not rotating as i can see in Unity

Can u please help.

This is reference script i use to load asset in android

```
IEnumerator receive(string message)
 {
 // Download compressed scene. If version 5 of the file named "Streamed-Level1.unity3d" was previously downloaded and cached.
 // Then Unity will completely skip the download and load the decompressed scene directly from disk.
 var download = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(message,19);
 yield return download;
 // Handle error
 if (download.error != null)
 {
     Debug.LogError(download.error);
     yield break;
 }
 // In order to make the scene available from LoadLevel, we have to load the asset bundle.
 // The AssetBundle class also lets you force unload all assets and file storage once it is no longer needed.
 var bundle = download.assetBundle;
 sceneNames = bundle.GetAllScenePaths ();
 // Load the level we have just downloaded
 SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNames[0]);
 }
}
```

And from my activity i use method to send message to UnityPlayerActivity to start player

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Main Camera", "receive", "https://MyServer/Level5.unity3d");
```

Comment: Did you attach the script to your Main Camera which actually called ""Main Camera"?

Comment: I have attached script to the object Cube which is actually rotating my object. if i attached same script to "Main Camera" camera revolves around the object. and it shows script for Object Cube is missing

Comment: W/Unity: The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing!
(Filename: ./Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1514)
W/Unity: The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing!(Filename: ./Runtime/Mono/MonoBehaviour.cpp Line: 1514)
W/Unity: The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object 'Main Camera') is missing!

Comment: Check out  my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The referenced script on this Behaviour is missing

Double click on that error from the Editor and it will show you the Objects that are causing that error. Remove the all the scripts attached to them then manually attach the scripts back to those Objects. This should fix the reference Object error.

If double-clicking on them does not show the affected GameObjects then select each GameObject and manually remove and re-attach each script attached to them. Do this from top to bottom and to all GameObjects. This should fix the reference Object error.

> I have attached script to the object Cube which is actually rotating
>   my object

I don't think you understand the `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` function.

- The first parameter is the name of the GameObject the script is
  attached to.
- The second parameter is the name of the function in that script that
  you want to call.
- The third parameter is the argument/parameter to pass to the function in that script that you want to call.

You said the script is attached to Gamebject named "Cube". You must pass *"Cube"* instead of *"Main Camera"* as the first parameter in the `UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage` function. Note that this is case sensitive.

```
UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Cube", "receive", "https://MyServer/Level5.unity3d");
```

Also, I don't know if it is possible to invoke a coroutine function from Java side since coroutines requires `StartCoroutine` to function. *I suggest you call a `void` function that starts a coroutine function if this does not work*.

```
void receive(string message)
{
    StartCoroutine(receiveCOR(message));
}

IEnumerator receiveCOR(string message)
 {
 // Download compressed scene. If version 5 of the file named "Streamed-Level1.unity3d" was previously downloaded and cached.
 // Then Unity will completely skip the download and load the decompressed scene directly from disk.
 var download = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload(message,19);
 yield return download;
 // Handle error
 if (download.error != null)
 {
     Debug.LogError(download.error);
     yield break;
 }
 // In order to make the scene available from LoadLevel, we have to load the asset bundle.
 // The AssetBundle class also lets you force unload all assets and file storage once it is no longer needed.
 var bundle = download.assetBundle;
 sceneNames = bundle.GetAllScenePaths ();
 // Load the level we have just downloaded
 SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNames[0]);
 }
}
```

Comment: I am downloading assetBundle for the scenes at run time. Thats why we have written receiver script to download and execute bundle and attached it to "Main Camera" as we do not know the name of the object which will be downloaded.

I cant understand why UnityPlayer cant find or execute the script which are bound in AssetBundle while we executing or loading assets from the server.

Is there any way to execute the script at run time after scene gets load on android device?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this today furiously trying to find the missing script, I highly suggest you check your Prefabs folder against every GameObject that exists in your scene which is a Prefab. One of these is going to be the issue more than likely.

I had removed a useless script from Visual Studio, then I removed it from the prefab object that existed in the scene, as opposed to the ACTUAL PREFAB in the Prefabs folder. Make sure to open each one, as one of them will show the error that you're looking for, since for this particular error clicking on it doesn't show you where it is.

Delete the missing script from the prefab not the GameObject in scene!